# Bind Plugin.Media fromViewModel

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a view model that handles the Plugin.Media to take a picture from the phone. The image will not show unless I have the code below (View Model) in the code-behind, then it works fine, which is defeating the object of me learning MVVM. I have also tried '`FileImageSource`' and used '`Source'` in its various ways.'

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

**View Model:**

```
public string FilePath { get => _filepath; set { _filepath = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
private string _filepath;

public Command CaptureImage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(TakePicture);
        }
    }

//

private async void TakePicture()
{
        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            //say something
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "FoodSnap",
            Name = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now),
            PhotoSize = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Custom,
            CustomPhotoSize = 50
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        FilePath = file.Path;            

}
```

**XAML:**

```
<pages:PopupPage
    xmlns:pages="clr- 
    namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TacticalFitness.ViewModels"
    x:Class="TacticalFitness.Views.PopUps.AddFoodSnapPopUp">

<BindableObject.BindingContext>
    <vm:AddSnapViewModel/>
</BindableObject.BindingContext>
<StackLayout>
        <Image Source="{Binding FilePath}" HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="LightGray" >
           <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding CaptureImage}"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
</StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: You say this code works?  So what is the problem?

Comment: It only works in the code behind of the XAML file where I can reference the x:Name of the Image control. It doesn't work from the view model.

Comment: I am assuming I have not got the binding properties correct in the XAML.

Comment: your image doesn't have an x:Name assigned

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand (i'm newbie). I thought the point of a ViewModel is you don't need an x:Name as this was just for the code behind. Do you use the image x:Name as the binding reference for the image control? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this from your view model, assign an instance of the view model to the `BindingContext` of your page, so that is the only line in your code-behind basically.

```
public YourPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
}
```

Now it should work.

*Update*

From your XAML I see:

```
<Image.Source>
    <StreamImageSource Stream="{Binding NewImage}"/>
</Image.Source>
```

Where `Stream` is a type of `Stream` but you are assigning an `ImageSource` to it. You can simply do this: `<Image HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="LightGray" Source="{Binding NewImage}">`

Comment: Apologies, I did bind the ViewModel in the XAML, I have updated XAML code above. I will try what you have mentioned and see if it helps things along.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: You put me on the right track...I did above and it works.