# Media Plugin not displaying an image after capture MVVM

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Media Plugin and everything worked fine until i have decided to move my logic to ViewModel.

This is my Xaml

```
<Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray" HasShadow="True">
                                <Image
                                    x:Name="Photo"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    HeightRequest="100"
                                    Source="{Binding postViewModel.SelectedPhoto}"
                                    VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                            </Frame>
```

My Binding to MasterViewModel

```
MasterPostsViewModel ViewModel;

protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
        
            BindingContext = ViewModel = new MasterPostsViewModel(Navigation);

        }
```

My Master

```
class MasterPostsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public PostViewModel postViewModel { get; set; }
        public CategoriesViewModel categoriesViewModel { get; set; }

        public MasterPostsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            postViewModel = new PostViewModel();

            categoriesViewModel = new CategoriesViewModel();

            postViewModel = new PostViewModel(navigation);
        }

    }
```

Taking Picture in View Model

```
private MediaFile _selectedPhoto;
   public MediaFile SelectedPhoto { get => _selectedPhoto; set => SetValue(ref 
    _selectedPhoto, value); }
     private async Task TakePicture()
            {
                await Permission();
                var imageSource = await DependencyService.Get<IMessage>().ShowActionSheet(AppResources.AlertPhoto, AppResources.AlertNewPhoto, AppResources.AlertGallery);
                if (imageSource == AppResources.AlertNewPhoto)
                {
                    var imageFileName = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions()
                    {
                        Name = $"{DateTime.UtcNow}.jpg",
                        DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Rear,
                        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                        SaveToAlbum = true
                    });
                    if (imageFileName == null) return;
                    else
                    {
                        SelectedPhoto = imageFileName;
    
                    }
                }
    }
```

I can see tthe adress of the picture however the picture doesnt display on my xaml. I have tried to follow this
[Bind Plugin.Media fromViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51273203/bind-plugin-media-fromviewmodel)

But still didnt work. Please some suggestion on what am i doing wrong

Comment: It looks like you're creating a new view model each time a page is shown, so the references are constantly different and you will never see the image because you're looking at a new instance of the view model. Make sure you set the view model only once and have `INotifyPropertyChanged` in place for your image property

Comment: Hello so i should not use  this? BindingContext = ViewModel =  new MasterPostsViewModel(Navigation);

Comment: Exactly. Just create the `MasterPostsViewModel` once, assign that to `BindingContext` and it should work

Comment: i am sorry but there is no change

Comment: Where did you call TakePicture? Are you using a binding command?

Answer (score 0):

I use you code and write a demo with binding a string, it works well. You can have a look at the code and may get some idea from it.

Code in xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="{Binding postViewModel.SelectedPhoto}"               
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button Text="click me" Command ="{Binding postViewModel.NewCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    MasterPostsViewModel ViewModel;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        BindingContext = ViewModel = new MasterPostsViewModel(Navigation);

    }
}

class MasterPostsViewModel 
{
    public PostViewModel postViewModel { get; set; }

    public MasterPostsViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        postViewModel = new PostViewModel();
    }

}

class PostViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _selectedPhoto;

    public ICommand NewCommand { private set; get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PostViewModel()
    {
        SelectedPhoto = "default text";
        NewCommand = new Command(TakePicture);
    }

    private void TakePicture()
    {
        SelectedPhoto = "test text After click button";
    }

    public string SelectedPhoto
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedPhoto != value)
            {
                _selectedPhoto = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedPhoto"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return _selectedPhoto;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample project has been uploaded [here](https://github.com/XfHua/data-binding-sample).

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look and let you know

Comment: I am sorry, but this still doesnt diplay anything

Comment: @TomashVovran Can you share me [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project so that I can test it on my side?